# Unable to get NPM to work on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, nodejs, npm

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and trying to install NodeJS and NPM on it. I am able to install NodeJS successfully but it did not install NPM which I think should have been installed when you install NodeJS.

I used the below command to install NPM on Ubuntu 16.04

```
sudo apt install npm
```

It installed NPM but when I try to execute any NPM command, this is the error I am getting.

```
npm: symbol lookup error: npm: undefined symbol: uv_os_homedir
```

Is there something I am missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```bash
curl -sSL https://github.com/libuv/libuv/archive/v1.9.0.tar.gz | sudo tar zxfv - -C /usr/local/src
cd /usr/local/src/libuv-1.9.0
sudo sh autogen.sh
sudo ./configure
sudo make 
sudo make install
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/src/libuv-1.9.0 && cd ~/
sudo ldconfig
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. The problem is with the version of libuv. I have installed 1.4.2 of libuv but after removing it and installing version 1.9.0 fixed the problem.